# Special column layout for the first row in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a web page that displays 4 images on each row.

I would like to make a first row a special one with a different column configuration from other rows as illustrated below.

[image]

So this special row will have 3 columns with the first one in a larger size.

Below is what I currently have and `<li>` represents a row and `<figure>` represents a column.

```
 <ul>
    <li>
    <% Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) { %>

        <% if (key%4 == 0 && key != 0) { %>
            </li><li>
        <% } %>
        <figure>

          ...

        </figure>
    <% }) %>
</ul>
```

I just can't get my head around adding this condition within the loop.

Comment: Isn't it too complicate way? Why don't you use css like here: https://jsfiddle.net/3nw3azyv/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be better to write in plain js file, but anyway, can you check this?

```
<% Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) { %>

    <% if (key === 0) { %>
        <figure class="double-size">

          ...

        </figure>
    <% } else { %>
        <% if ((key+1)%4 == 0 && key != 0) { %>
            </li><li>
        <% } %>

        <figure>

          ...

        </figure>
    <% } %>

<% }) %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've tried this but it just won't execute the statement within `if (key ===0)`. It only executes `else` statement.

Comment: can you post a copy of the "data" object you use?

Comment: `key` was string so it wasn't doing the proper calculation. It was concatenating. Thank you it works for me.